# Android: Retrieving data from previous activity

Tags: android, google-maps

at the moment I have my user and password fields in a login screen.

The user enters these credentials and then on successful login the login activity its closed and the user is directed to a menu page.

What I want to do is use the username entered in the login field to create a 'Hello USERNAME' sentence in the menu.

not really too sure of how to do this. Could someone help.

Comment: check this: http://lovingandroid.blogspot.com/2011/08/passing-values-from-one-activity-to.html

Answer (score 1):

Do something like this

**In Login Activity**

```
    String userName;
         if(login_ok){
        final Intent i = new Intent(Login.this, Welcome.class);
        i.putExtras("userName",userName);//sending checked value to next activity
        startActivity(i);
    }
```

**in welcome Activity**

```
TextView view1 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView1);
Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
String user=bundle.getString("userName"));
view1.setText("Welcome "+user);
```